# Исключение при подключении к MYSQL через JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Запускаю maven-проект с элементарным кодом:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/users?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "12344321");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Программа задумывается и выдает warning:

```
[WARNING] thread Thread[mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup,5,test] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup,5,test] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to  via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=test,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy (ThreadGroup.java:778)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Соединение закрыто. В чем может быть причина?

П.С.:Если в командную строку сборки проекта добавить *-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false* то warning'и пропадают, но хотелось бы разобраться, почему не получается остановить потоки.

Answer (score 0):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?serverTimezone=UTC
```

Укажите порт, к которому надо подключится, в моем примере - 3306

Comment: Добавление порта в url не помогло.

Comment: @PavelSolokha, а чего вы вообще хотите добиться этим кодом? Вы создаете подключение и через 100 милисекунд его закрываете. Сейчас попробовал у себя потестить - все работает, подключение создается и не падает. Проверяйте на каком порту сидит БД или имя БД

Comment: хочу понять, почему выдает такие warning'и.
В идеале такой тест должен проходить за пару секунд, а у меня он повисает на 18 секунд.

Comment: Похоже ответ тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465161/exception-while-trying-to-run-java-program-from-maven

Comment: да, я видел это обсуждение, и уже написал, что добавление -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false в строку запуска проблему решает.
Но мне кажется это не совсем нормально, когда простейший код выполняется долго и выдает warning.
пытаюсь разобраться почему, но пока не могу найти информацию.
Ну, а вариант с System.exit(0); это совсем крайние меры.